# Encontrar n fechas mas cercanas a una fecha dada

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día.

Intento recuperar, con base a un grupo de fechas dadas por un usuario, las fechas de una tabla que mas se acerquen a las fechas dadas.

Los datos de prueba y las tablas son así:

```
create table PAC_ID_T
(
  IdPaciente int,
  NHC varchar (10)
);

insert into PAC_ID_T (IdPaciente,NHC)
values (3000,'100111');

create table Datos$
(
  NHC Varchar (10),
  Fecha date
);

insert into Datos$ (NHC, Fecha) values
( '100111' , '2013-07-24' ),
('100111' , '2012-08-01' );


create table SIGNOSVITALES_T
(
  IdPaciente int,
  FechaVisita date
);


insert into SIGNOSVITALES_T (IdPaciente, FechaVisita)
select IdPaciente, FechaVisita from
(
              select   3000  IdPaciente , '2011-01-03' FechaVisita
    union all select   3000  IdPaciente , '2011-01-06' 
    union all select   3000  IdPaciente , '2012-07-24' 
    union all select   3000  IdPaciente , '2012-07-26' 
    union all select   3000  IdPaciente , '2012-07-31' 
    union all select   3000  IdPaciente , '2013-08-01' 
    union all select   3000  IdPaciente , '2013-05-22' 

)t
```

Al momento tengo este script, pero solamente puedo recuperar una de las fechas [(Prueba del script)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e5476/10):

```
select   a.NHC,  max(date_format(a.FechaVisita,'%d/%m/%Y')) FechaVisita
from
(
    select p.IdPaciente, P.NHC, a.FechaVisita, timestampdiff  (day , a.FechaVisita ,  h.Fecha) DiasCercanos
    from Datos$ H
    left join PAC_ID_T p
    on h.NHC = p.NHC
    left join SIGNOSVITALES_T a 
    on p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente 
    where  timestampdiff  (day , a.FechaVisita ,  h.Fecha) > 0 

)a
left join 
(
    select distinct  H.NHC ,  a.FechaVisita ,   min(timestampdiff  (day , a.FechaVisita ,  H.Fecha ) )DiasCercanos
    from Datos$ H
    left join PAC_ID_T p
    on h.NHC = p.NHC
    left join SIGNOSVITALES_T a
    on p.IdPaciente = a.IdPaciente
    where a.IdPaciente is not null 
    and A.FechaVisita <= H.Fecha  
    group by   H.NHC,a.FechaVisita
)f
on a.NHC = f.NHC and a.DiasCercanos = f.DiasCercanos
where f.NHC is not null
group by a.NHC
ORDER BY a.NHC ASC
```

En este caso, las fechas dadas están reflejadas en la tabla Datos$, en esta tabla existen dos fechas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la tabla en donde necesito encontrar las fechas mas cercanas a esta es la tabla SIGNOSVITALES_T, esta tiene las siguientes fechas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, necesito recuperar las dos fechas mas cercanas a las definidas en la tabla Datos$, en este caso serian :

2012-07-31 (Es la única que devuelve hasta el momento)
2013-05-22 (Esta es la segunda fecha que necesito devolver, debe ser fecha menor a la indicada en la tabla Datos$)

Que me hace falta ?

Comment: Buen dia, es un poco complicado resolver la estructura de datos que tienes solo mirando la consulta, sin siquiera un ejemplo de datos devueltos, o de los datos de cada tabla. lo mejor que puedes hacer es expresar tu estructura (o un ejemplo simplificado de ésta) en [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) y compartir el link generado por tu consulta de ejemplo, o en su defecto poner "capturas" de los datos de las distintas tablas mencionadas

Comment: @RicardoGalain Capturas de los datos no. Es importante promover prácticas acordes con las normas del sitio y con el bienestar de todos, y transcribir cosas desde imagenes para replicar algo es muy engorroso. Así mismo, se promueve que la pregunta sea autocontenida y no dependa de enlaces externos. Saludos! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  S.IdPaciente, 
        S.FechaVisita, 
        F.Fecha,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, S.FechaVisita, F.Fecha) AS 'DifDias',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY F.Fecha ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DAY, S.FechaVisita, F.Fecha)) AS 'RN'
        FROM SIGNOSVITALES_T S
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   P.IdPaciente,
                    D.Fecha
                    FROM PAC_ID_T  P
                    INNER JOIN Datos$ D
                        ON P.NHC =  D.NHC
            ) F
            ON F.IdPaciente = S.IdPaciente
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, S.FechaVisita, F.Fecha) > 0
)
SELECT  IdPaciente,
    Fecha,
    FechaVisita
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Salida:

```
| IdPaciente |      Fecha | FechaVisita |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|       3000 | 2012-08-01 |  2012-07-31 |
|       3000 | 2013-07-24 |  2013-05-22 |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/545d3/1/0

#### Detalle:

- Básicamente combinamos cada fila de `SIGNOSVITALES_T` con las dos correspondientes al paciente en `Datos$`
- Luego, buscamos la diferencia en días entre `FechaVisita` y cada `Fecha`, descartamos las `FechaVisita` que fueran posteriores a `Fecha`
- Ordenamos por la diferencia en días de menor a mayor y por cada grupo de `Fecha`, con `ROW_NUMBER()` generamos un número de fila
- Por último consultamos la tabla generada y solo listamos las filas número 1 que serán las fechas más cercanas.

Comment: Gracias no expresa mi asombro por la respuesta... Genial... gracias.